# How to set left margin in PowerPoint textbox using VSTO

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint, margin

I'm taking some user data and adding it to a PowerPoint presentation using VSTO.  To get the formatting to look right, though I need to be able to set the left margin of some of the text in the textbox.  There will be an initial block of text followed by another, indented block. For example (underlines added to emphasize spacing):

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
>   vestibulum elementum neque id rhoncus.
>   In fermentum eros nec dolor lobortis
>   sit amet fermentum est consequat.
>   Curabitur eleifend nunc eu odio
>   vehicula ut elementum erat aliquam. Ut
>   adipiscing ipsum sit amet leo pulvinar
>   hendrerit. Cum sociis natoque
>   penatibus et magnis dis parturient
>   montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla
>   non neque in velit lacinia tempor et a
>   lacus.
>        
> ___________Cras auctor bibendum urna, a facilisis lacus
>   lacinia non. 
>        
> ___________Nullam at quam a mauris consequat vulputate sed eu
>   sapien. 
>        
> ___________Fusce sed urna nulla, ut sagittis lacus. Pellentesque
>   tortor 
>        
> ___________augue, scelerisque at aliquet a, pretium ac
>   ipsum.

I can get this effect by setting `Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.IndentLevel = 2` on the lower block of text.  However, I cannot figure out how to programmatically set the value of the margin.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taken care of via `Shape.TextFrame.MarginRight` and `Shape.TextFrame.MarginLeft` and the like.

Comment: Not exactly what I needed, but you pointed me in the right direction so you get the answer.  Setting the TextFrame.MarginLeft sets the left margin for the entire textbox (which doesn't help me get my indented block), but after I set TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0, I was able to set TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[2].LeftMargin and the block of text would actually indent properly.
Thanks

Comment: Ah got it, great you worked it out. I should have read your question a little closer to find that you wanted the margin within the textframe instead of the actual text frame. Sorry about that.